# Setting up a wireless connection from the command line on Debian

Tags: debian, wifi, nmcli

I have a laptop with a proprietary Intel wifi card that I am trying to use to connect to a WPA/WPA2 network (called simply "Network")

I've installed iwlwifi, net-tools, and network-manager

I ran nmtui to set up the wifi, and all seemed well, and nmtui reported it was connected, but when I tried to ping 8.8.4.4 I got an unreachable network. For some reason nm[cli|tui] does not work. I've also tried wpa_supplicant, but wasn't able to get very far with that either.

I'm hoping that there's some error in how I've set up my wireless interface that someone can spot and help me fix.

I know that "Network" works because I am duel-booting Ubuntu alongside the Debian system and I have wifi working with Ubuntu.

iwconfig

```
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Network"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: A2:63:91:25:81:67   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0
```

nmcli

```
wlo1: connected to Network
    "Intel Wireless 3165 (Dual Band Wireless AC 3165)"
    wifi (iwlwifi), B8:81:98:51:75:5C, hw
    ip4 default
    inet4 192.168.1.23/24
    inet6 fe80::bd90:9bfa:c408:e458/64

enp1s0: unmanaged
    "Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller"
    ethernet (r8169), EC:8E:B5:A3:5C:02, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
    loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
    servers: 192.168.1.1
    interface: wlo1

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(5) manual pages for complete usage details.
```

nmcli device show

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         B8:81:98:51:75:5C
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Network
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.23/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::bd90:9bfa:c408:e458/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         EC:8E:B5:A3:5C:02
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.35/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::ee8e:b5ff:fea3:5c02/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

nmcli connection show

```
NAME      UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE 
Network   21931e14-0cda-46b2-91c2-120447e287bd  802-11-wireless  wlo1   
SAndroid  62d7a99d-8ef7-404c-b18b-df31ebb3b7bc  802-11-wireless  --
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
```

lspci | grep Wireless

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

Comment: Can you do 'route -n' and post the output as edit of your question?

Comment: yes, I've added it

Comment: Hmm -- this is tricky -- I can't figure it out . Please, add the output of ´ping -c 1 192.168.1.1´. Please, also comment out  the last two lines in your ´/etc/network/interfaces´ by prepending them with ´#´. Then restart your laptop. This will add this interface to the list of network-managed interfaces (managed by network-manager) -- your ethernet card and your wifi card may be conflicting when managed by different startup scripts...

Comment: The output of ´ifconfig´(in contrast to ´iwconfig´) may also be helpful -- sorry for so many requests...

Answer (score 1):

It was a driver problem

For those who have the same problem please run the command

```
apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-free linux-firmware-nonfree
```